# What uniform is this person wearing?

Tags: identification, uniform, lithuania

The subject in question was a Lithuanian Army Private from 1944 to 1945 mentioned in a history we have found.

There is a hammer and sickle emblem on the brim.

This makes me think that, as part of the Soviet Union invasion of Lithuania, et al. in 1940, the subject could have been conscripted to fight Germany on behalf of the Soviet Union under the Lithuanian Army.

[image]

Any help in identifying the uniform could help clear things up. I've read about the 16th rifle division and the 1941+ "Lithuanian" 16th rifle division which could be clues. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

“БФ” on the shoulders means Baltic Fleet. One narrow strip means Senior Seaman rank ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_of_the_Soviet_Union_(1943%E2%80%931955))). Though he also could be a marine.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right there.The subject in question actually had that photo alongside another in civilian attire, looking remarkably different. This means the person in this photo wasn't necessarily a Lithuanian Army Private then (considering the Soviet Union harm against Lithuania).

Comment: @ItsaMeMario If this person’s name is known, there are databases of Soviet WW2 servicemen which can be helpful, for example https://pamyat-naroda.ru/ . But you will need the Cyrillic version of the name.